# Producing a genetically modified animal with cell walls

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology

I'm curious if there has been any genetic experiments **transferring cell wall producing genes into the genome of a animal model organism** such as the fruit fly (*Drosophila melanogaster*) or a larger animal such as a mouse (*Mus musculus*).

If there hasn't what do you think would happen, if anything at all?

Thanks!

Comment: They already have cells with walls.

Comment: I don't know of any animals with cell walls unlise your considering something like chitin as a cell wall, which it isn't. Please provide examples if you have any. Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is it's very complicated. Plants devote a significant portion of their genomes to cell wall construction and integrating that into an animal, I imagine, would be like integrating a helicopter into a battle tank.

Comment: Unless some experiments have been made testing this (which I doubt) this question can only generate speculation.  Voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Mammalian cells have a semi permeable membrane not a true cell wall like a plant cell. I could imagine that if the semi permeable membrane were replaced with a plant like cell wall then osmosis and other biochemical processes necessary to the organisms growth and survival could not occur correctly.